# How to use a simple module that I created in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It's been two weeks that I've been stuck on probably a very basic and simple problem. I'd like to create a very simple program (I am working on a BMI calculator for example) in what I'd like to use a module. I wrote it and I still don't understand why it's not working. I modified it many times to try to find the solution, so I had many different error messages, but on this version of my program, the message is (after it asks to enter the height):

```
Enter you height (in inches): 70

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Julien/Desktop/Modules/Module ex2/M02 ex2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from modBmi import *
  File "C:/Users/Julien/Desktop/Modules/Module ex2\modBmi.py", line 11, in <module>
    modBmi()
  File "C:/Users/Julien/Desktop/Modules/Module ex2\modBmi.py", line 5, in modBmi
    heightSq = (height)**2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'"
```

This is my code (for information, my module is in a separated file "modBmi.py" but in the same folder than my main program):

```
#Python 3.4.3
#BMI calculator

def modBmi():
#ask the height
    height = input ("Enter you height (in inches): ")
    #create variable height2
    heightSq = int(height)**2
#ask th weight
    weight = input ("Enter you weight (in pounds): ")
#calculate bmi
    bmi = int(weight) * 703/int(heighSq)

modBmi()

#import all informatio from modBmi 
from modBmi import *

#diplay the result of the calculated BMI 
print("Your BMI is: " +(bmi))
```

Comment: Thank you it helped me to go further ! Nevertheless, it still say that bmi is not defined (in my main program) when I test the program, after I enter the height and the weight.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.x, `input()` will return a string.

```
height = input("Enter you height (in inches): ")
print (type(height))
# <class 'str'>
```

Therefore:

```
height ** 2
```

will result in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/SO_Testing.py", line 45, in <module>
    height ** 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

Which is exactly the error you are seeing. In order to fix this, simply cast the result of `input` to an integer, using `int()`

```
height = int(input("Enter you height (in inches): "))   
print (type(height))
# <class 'int'>
```

Now you will be able to perform the mathematical operations on `height`.

**EDIT**

The error you have shown says the problem occurs at:

```
heightSq = (height)**2
```

However, the code you have provided *does* cast `height` to an int. Casting to an int will solve your problem.

**EDIT 2**

In order to obtain the value for `bmi` outside the function you need to `return` the value:

```
def modBmi():
#ask the height
    height = input ("Enter you height (in inches): ")
    #create variable height2
    heightSq = int(height)**2
#ask th weight
    weight = input ("Enter you weight (in pounds): ")
#calculate bmi
    bmi = int(weight) * 703/int(heighSq)

    return bmi

bmi = modBmi()
```

Comment: OK ! Thank you so much, I think I start to understand. But really thank you ! I was felling that I was in front of a wall... Thank you again and again and again !

Comment: No problem, if this answered your question, don't forgot to upvote and accept so that it can be marked as solved.